# Linq- Issue in custom order by

Tags: c#, linq

```
var CustomStatus = new[] { "PAG", "ASG", "WIP", "COMP", "SEN" };

List<CDSHelper> HelperList = new List<CDSHelper>();
// Getting the values from API to fill the object and
// finally doing the custom order by

var result = HelperList.OrderBy(a => Array.IndexOf(CustomStatus, a.status));
```

I am using custom order by to sort the HelperList objects.I have around 18 status totally .Out of the 18 status i want to order the list based on CustomStatus,rest of order should come in the list after CustomStatus status.Using the above code i can able to get the CustomStatus at the end of the HelperList. How to acheive this?

Comment: Did you try creating a list with custom status appended with the other statutes and then use the same order by expression?

Comment: Beware, that for large number of item, it can be very slow. Ordeby is O(n*log n) and index O(n). Your customized order by is O(n^2 * log n).

Comment: Yes Its hitting the performance.But this is what my requirement.The other option is first extracting list data based on custom status and put it into separate list then finally add the non custom status data's into list.Which one is the best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the easiest way to do it is use `OrderBy` then `ThenBy` however you need to change the `-1` `IndexOf` will return if the item does not exist into a higher value so items not in the list become last.

```
var result = HelperList.OrderBy(a => {
                         var x = Array.IndexOf(CustomStatus, a.status);
                         if(x < 0)
                            x = int.MaxValue;
                         return x;
                     }).ThenBy(a => a.status); //Sort alphabetically for the ties at the end.
```

Another way is reverse the order of `CustomStatus` then use `OrderByDecending`

```
var CustomStatus = new[] { "SEN", "COMP", "WIP", "ASG","PAG" };

List<CDSHelper> HelperList = new List<CDSHelper>();
// Getting the values from API to fill the object and
// finally doing the custom order by

var result = HelperList.OrderByDecending(a => Array.IndexOf(CustomStatus, a.status))
                       .ThenBy(a.status);
```

Comment: Thanks scott. First option works perfectly without thenby. Because I don't want to Sort alphabetically.

Comment: Awesome! Totally helped me you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb359438.aspx) for `CustomStatus`. You don't need to know the index of the status in `CustomStatus` you only need to know if it is in the list. Lookup in a `HashSet` is an O(1) operation. In an array it is O(n):

```
var CustomStatus = new HashSet<string> { "PAG", "ASG", "WIP", "COMP", "SEN" };

var result = HelperList.OrderBy(a => !CustomStatus.Contains(a.status))
                       .ThenBy(a => a.status).ToList();
```

`OrderBy` sorts the list by the boolean value returned from `!CustomStatus.Contains(a.status)`. First all values contained in the `HashSet` then the rest. Each group is then ordered alphabetically by status.